# Segmentation fault in v8 hello world when using TryCatch

Tags: c++, v8

I am trying to use v8 in my C++ application. I am stuck on the helloworld itself!

The helloworld at https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started works just fine. Now I am trying to catch exceptions/error in the code. So I used TryCatch trycatch;.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    HandleScope handle_scope;
    Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();
    Context::Scope context_scope(context);
    TryCatch trycatch; /* TO CATCH EXCETIONS/ERRORS */
    Handle<String> source = String::New("xyz();");
    Handle<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);
    Handle<Value> result = script->Run();
    if (result.IsEmpty()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Exception: %s\n",
                *String::AsciiValue(trycatch.Exception()));
        return -1;
    }
    String::AsciiValue ascii(result);
    printf("%s\n", *ascii);
    context.Dispose();

    return 0;
}
```

The exceptions are caught fine but the program does not terminate properly. It generates a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `String::AsciiValue(trycatch.Exception())` is a proper string? Try e.g. `char *s = *String::AsciiValue(trycatch.Exception());`, and check that `s` is valid in a debugger.

Comment: Aren't you looking for `trycatch.Message()` instead? And also note that they may be no message associated with an exception and then 'an empty handle is returned' so you probably have to check for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a foolish thing. I had long back installed libv8-dev and forgotten about it. And now I installed V8 from source. So I had two versions of V8 on my system. I uninstalled libv8-dev and the problem has been solved.